# How to modify a file in a Docker container when deploying with Terraform and Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, terraform

As a part of a bigger module, I want to deploy an `nginx` container and replace its default `nginx.conf`. The new config should be built using Terraform *resources*' data which is generated at the time of deployment. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Create a file using terraform resource data and mount it as volume to nginx deployment.

Comment: ...probably putting the actual file in a Kubernetes ConfigMap.

Comment: @DavidMaze yep, that’s the solution I came up with, I’ll post a detailed answer a bit later

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to replace the standard nginx.conf with a dynamically generated one following these steps:

1. Create a template config file with placeholders for dynamic data
2. Parse the file using Terraform's `template_file` *data source*
3. Store the parsed data in a ConfigMap and mount the map as a volume for the Nginx container

Step by step:

Create nginx.conf template named **nginx-conf.tpl**:

```
events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}
http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name ${server_name};

    location /_plugin/kibana {
        proxy_pass https://${elasticsearch_kibana_endpoint};
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://${elasticsearch_endpoint};
    }
  }
}
```

Parse the **nginx-conf.tpl** template with the following Terraform code:

```
data "template_file" "nginx" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/nginx-conf.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    elasticsearch_endpoint        = "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.example-name.endpoint}"
    elasticsearch_kibana_endpoint = "${aws_elasticsearch_domain.example-name.kibana_endpoint}"
    server_name                   = "${var.server_name}"
  }
}
```

Create a ConfigMap and store the parsed template there with `nginx.conf` key:

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "nginx"
  }
  data = {
    "nginx.conf" = data.template_file.nginx.rendered
  }
}
```

Finally, mount the ConfigMap key as a container volume:

```
# ...
spec {
  # ...
  container {
    # ...
    volume_mount {
      name       = "nginx-conf"
      mount_path = "/etc/nginx"
    }
  }
  volume {
    name = "nginx-conf"
    config_map {
      name = "nginx"
      items {
        key  = "nginx.conf"
        path = "nginx.conf"
      }
    }
  }
}
# ...
```

That's it. Nginx server will start using the provided config.

Useful links: [Kubernetes ConfigMap as volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap), [Terraform temple_file data source doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file).